# GWT issue with IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt, gwt-platform

I had a project using GWT and gwt-presenter which is compatible with 
most browsers: IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. 
And since the migration to GWT Platform, my project does not works with IE9 
except in compatibility mode(display page as if we were 
using  an earlier version of Internet Explorer) and it's still 
compatible with others browsers. 
what is the problem exactly?? i dont know but the browser loads the 
file then it it displays a blank page and no errors are reported! ! 
is there  anyone who has been faced a problem like this with IE9? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you are not compiling the IE permutation? Or maybe you're using an older version of GWT (I use 2.4 and it works in IE9 for sure)?

Comment: I also use GWT 2.4 and GWTP 0.7, and after your comment I have compiled only IE9 permutation, by defining user.agent=ie9, but the problem persists.

Comment: I would add lots of client-side logging messages, enable the browser console logging and try to pinpoint where exactly execution of the program halts. I had similar happen to me but it was simply because I had forgotten to let GWT compile the IE versions (I turned that off to speed up development and testing).

Answer (score 0):

GWT has special section of documentation for IE9 and you can find it here - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9

Note - GWT has for quite a while now supported ie9 as browser permutation that can be added in the module.gwt.xml file.